# Using a PDF builder (maybe domPDF) and relative urls are not working. Need to convert to absolute urls

Tags: php, dompdf, relative-url

I have an application on a website developed by a third party (and no documentation). I think it uses a combination of symfony, dompdf and others to build a "shopping cart" of pages that you can download as a PDF. Anyway, I've managed to do a number of edits to this over time, but I'm having problems with relative URLs. They are breaking and resulting in a 404. I've managed to fix those types of links when in a list with this line:

```
$this->content = str_replace('<li><a href="', '<li><a href="' . $this->frontUrl . '', $this->content);
```

But the problem still persists in links in other spots, see the bottom of this bio for a URL as an example: https://www.bipc.com/briefcasebir/web/briefcase/render.pdf?token=1619124576&filename=briefcase.pdf

I'm trying to rework this with a way to target any `<a>` tags that contain relative urls and add the "frontUrl" to convert it to absolute. Maybe there's a better way? But I don't think I can fix this with javascript either since it's creating a PDF.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you already tried to either set the `<base>` tag in your HTML-to-PDF templates, or to set protocol, host & base path on your `Dompdf` object (cf. https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1086#issuecomment-174356414)?

Comment: @nosurs, using <base> worked perfectly. Helps me get rid of some nasty hacks I had in place that also worked. But my only remaining problem is with URLs that use the `tel:` protocol. They are also getting prefixed with the base URL now too. I can't seem to target that directly either. Is there something else I should prepend `tel` with?

Comment: I'm continuing this here since @nosurs' reply worked for my original question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67290546/converting-an-anchor-tag-to-plain-text-with-jquery