# Converting an anchor tag to plain text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running into a problem with my output of an HTML-to-PDF process where my anchor tags that contain the `tel:` protocol are kicking back errors when clicked. It turns out that these `hrefs` are being seen as relative URLs unlike how `mailto:` is recognized as it's own thing.

I figure that if I can target these elements directly, I could take their content, hide the `<a>` tag entirely and only display the content in a new element. Maybe this is overthinking it?

Here's where I went: https://jsfiddle.net/BIPC_Sydor/yL8suwno/1/

I wanted to try and target each instance of an `<a>` tag within a specific div (class of menu). Then copy the content of each instance into a new `<p>` tag (class of pdf). From there I could hide the old `<a>` and stylize the new `<p>`. Unfortunately, it's outputting both anchors' content in more instances that I expected. Is this doable?

My code from the fiddle:

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu">
  <a href="page.html">Page 1</a>
  <a href="page2.html">Page 2</a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$( '.menu a' ).each(function( i ) {
  var res = $('.menu a').text();
  $('.menu a').after('<p class="pdf">'+ res +'</p>');
});
```

Comment: Have you looked at `jQuery.replace`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `after(function)` and chain `hide()` to hide the `<a>` as well

```js
$('.menu a').after(function() {
  return $('<p>', {class: 'pdf', text: $(this).text()})
}).hide()
```

```css
p.pdf { color: red }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <a href="page.html">Page 1</a>
  <a href="page2.html">Page 2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: So this worked in the example, but when i reenabled the HTML-to-PDF that this is used in, it didn't work. Is there a way to do this with straight php?

Answer (score 0):

use `value` as well in your each() method, and use the value reference to update nodes, else it will update all the nodes.

```js
$( '.menu a' ).each(function( index,value ) {
  var res = $(value).text(); // value is for current iteration
  $(value).after('<p class="pdf">'+ res +'</p>');
  // do something else...
});
```

Reference here : https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 0):

You can, of course, also do this without jQuery:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.menu a').forEach(a=>{
 a.style.display="none";
 a.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend",`<p class="pdf">${a.textContent}</p>`)
});
```

```css
p.pdf { color: red }
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <a href="page.html">Page 1</a>
  <a href="page2.html">Page 2</a>
</div>
<p><a href="somewhere.html">no action was taken here, since this is not part of the menu div.</a> And that is a fact.</p>
```